# push_back em Vector 2D, emitindo erro "no matching function for call"

Tags: c++11, vector, 2d

Sou iniciante em programação C++, por isso peço desculpas antecipadas.

Conforme esta dúvida respondida [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312682/two-dimensional-vector-push-back), é possível usar `std::vector`, 2D (grid) com `push_back()` diretamente (`variavel[indice].push_back(...)`) incrementando unidimensionalmente, e irregularmente/desproporcionalmente as colunas e/ou linhas.

A struct:

```
typedef struct SCoord {
  unsigned int x, y; 

  SCoord(): x(0), y(0)
  {}
} TCoord;
```

Em determinada parte do código efetua-se a inicialização de um vetor 2D, como a seguir:

```cpp
// CRIADOR DE POSIÇÕES
TCoord makePos(ulint x, ulint y){
  TCoord r;
  r.x = x;
  r.y = y;
  return r;
}

// Declaração da variável Grid, com tamanho de linha "gridlin" (inicializado)
std::vector<std::vector<TCoord>> *Grid = new std::vector<std::vector<TCoord>>(gridlin, std::vector<TCoord>());

/* ALGUMA PROCESSAMENTOS AQUI ...
 */

// Adição de celula/coluna à uma linha qualquer (certamente existente)
Grid[i].push_back(makePos(
  sortear(0, 50),
  sortear(0, 50)
));
```

O código acima é real, porém picotado (resumo), já que está inserido dentro de um contexto de mais de 3 mil linhas.

Há uma erro em tempo de compilação, emitido exatamente para a linha contendo o `push_back()`.

`error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::vector<SCoord> >::push_back(TCoord)’
         ));
          ^
note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/vector:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/random.h:34,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/random:50,
                 from lib/rng.h:13,
                 from lib/comum.h:17,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_vector.h:901:7: note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::vector<SCoord>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<SCoord> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::vector<SCoord>]
       push_back(const value_type& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_vector.h:901:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘TCoord {aka SCoord}’ to ‘const value_type& {aka const std::vector<SCoord>&}’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_vector.h:919:7: note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = std::vector<SCoord>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<SCoord> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::vector<SCoord>]
       push_back(value_type&& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_vector.h:919:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘TCoord {aka SCoord}’ to ‘std::vector<std::vector<SCoord> >::value_type&& {aka std::vector<SCoord>&&}’`

Estou mais acostumado a lidar com o padrão c, usando array e ponteiros, sendo que minha experiencia em c, em especial C++ (std::vector) é bem limitada. Caso haja alguma ideia de solução fico desde já agradecido.

Duas coisas precisam ser destacadas deste código, primeiro **"no matching function for call"** e depois, logo abaixo, uma nota que informa **"no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘TCoord {aka SCoord}’ to ‘const value_type& {aka const std::vector<SCoord>&}’"**

Answer (score 0):

Bom, como mencionado, meu conhecimento em C++ é limitado.

Ao pesquisar [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998591/cannot-access-element-of-2d-heap-vector-using-operator) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493829/accessing-the-operator-from-a-pointer), embora não tenha obtido todo o conhecimento envolvido no assunto, percebi que ao contrário de array, como `TCoord **Grid`, que são acessados diretamente (referenciado) com o [operador []](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/), da seguinte forma: `Grid[0][0]`; um ponteiro para `std::vector`, necessita ser acessado desferenciadamente, neste caso `*Grid[0][0]`.

Assim, conclui-se que `Grid[i]` acessa diretamente `std::vector<std::vector<TCoord>>`, independentemente de "i", portanto, `push_back()` deve receber um `std::vector<TCoord>`, enquanto um `*Grid[i]`, é o próprio vetor 2D, `std::vector<std::vector<TCoord>>`, em seu índice "i" que é um `std::vector<TCoord>` e que recebe no push_back(), um TCoord.

Uma forma também de acessar seria `Grid->at(i)`